# Cannot install SWinTypeLibs, but need to know what functions are in ComCreate(Word.Application)

Tags: r, vba, rdcomclient

Please forgive me if this is not perfect but this is my first post.

I am currently working on trying to transform a large number of .docx documents into .pdf

I have found the RDCOMClient package which has done wonders. However I now need to add alt text into my charts. The code I am using is below:

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)

# this will destroy all objects in your workspace so be careful
# rm(list = ls()) # deletes all data frames

file <- "directory"

wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")  # create COM object
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- FALSE #opens a Word application instance visibly if true 
wordApp[["Documents"]]$Add() #adds new blank docx in your application
wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(Filename=file) #opens your docx in wordApp

#THIS IS THE MAGIC    
wordApp[["ActiveDocument"]]$SaveAs("Directory", 
                                   FileFormat=17) #FileFormat=17 saves as .PDF

wordApp[["ActiveDocument"]]$Close(SaveChanges = 1) # says there are no changes that need saving
```

Where there is function in double [] like Documents is there something for chart.

I have found a full list of them for excel at the link here: http://www.omegahat.net/RDCOMClient/Docs/introduction.html

However I tried to install the SWinTypeLibs package to get the same thing for word using the following code:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("omegahat/SWinTypeLibs")
```

and keep getting an error

if anyone has a list for word like the excel above would really need it.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

James

Answer (score 2):

I've applied a quick fix to the .Rd docs in the original package from omegahat. You can find it here--should compile now.

[karnner2/SWinTypeLibs](https://github.com/Karnner2/SWinTypeLibs)

```
devtools::install_github("Karnner2/SWinTypeLibs")
```